# Python: indexing floats?

Tags: python, string, floating-point, indexing

I have two sets of data that I am reading via nested for loops in Python.  I need to match lines of the two different text files using a common number (time). In the two files, time is written differently (ex.  21:53:28.339 vs. 121082008.3399).  I only need the last four digits of the times to match them up, for example from 21:53:28.339, I only need '8.339'.  For the most part, indexing the number as a string works just fine (ex: timeList[nid][7:]), except for situations such as the numbers listed above, where python rounds .3399 to .34.

Is there a way for me to keep the numbers in float form and to select unrounded digits from the data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

edit - using Decimal exclusively - with full example

```
import decimal

def simplify(text):
    # might be a : separated value
    text = text.split(':')[-1]
    # turn into decimal
    number = decimal.Decimal(text)
    # remove everything but the ones place and forwards
    number = number - (number/10).quantize(1, rounding=decimal.ROUND_FLOOR) * 10
    # truncate to the thousandths
    return number.quantize(decimal.Decimal('.001'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_FLOOR)

a = '121082008.3399'
b = '21:53:28.339'

assert simplify(a) == simplify(b)
print simplify(a), '=', simplify(b)
```

---

Scott if you compare the numbers using strings then you don't need any floats and there will be no 'rounding' going on.

```
'8.339' == '8.339'
```

or, if you have

```
a = '8.3399'
b = '8.339'
```

then

```
a[:-1] == b
```

however if you do decide to work with them as 'numbers', then as Ignacio pointed out, you can use decimals.

```
from decimal import Decimal
number_a = Decimal(a[:-1])
number_b = Decimal(b)
```

now

```
number_a == number_b
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

It appears from your description that you want to compare using one digit before the decimal point and 3 digits after the decimal point, using truncation instead of rounding. So just do that:

```
>>> def extract(s):
...     i = s.find('.')
...     return s[i-1:i+4]
...
>>> map(extract, ['21:53:28.339', '121082008.3399'])
['8.339', '8.339']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`decimal.Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) instead of `float`.

Comment: Any ideas on how I can ignore the first part of the number (from 121082008.3399 I only want 8.339 - basically just chopping off the first and last part of the number.) while using the decimal module?  Thanks!

Comment: @Scott: using the decimal module is extreme overkill  ... just chop up your strings; see my answer.